# How to combine three ffmpeg commands into one ?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am pretty confused that how to combine three ffmpeg commnads into one which also consists of two inputs.

```
// rescale with certain dimension 
ffmpeg -i front.mp4 -filter_complex scale=600:400 rescale.mp4

//Attach to image
ffmpeg -i 600800.jpg  -i rescale.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" final.mp4

// After Changed to specific even size Burn Subtitles with Draw Text
ffmpeg -i final.mp4 -filter_complex "drawtext=fontfile=Lucida Grande.ttf:text='I am TEXT':fontsize=72:fontcolor=white:x=50:y=100,subtitles=sample.srt:force_style='Fontsize=22,OutlineColour=&H55000000,BorderStyle=3'" CheckMe.mp4
```

Comment: As per the ffmpeg tag, all command line usage questions should be posted on [su] or [video.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i front.mp4 -i 600800.jpg -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=600:400[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,drawtext=fontfile=Lucida Grande.ttf:text='I am TEXT':fontsize=72:fontcolor=white:x=50:y=100,subtitles=sample.srt:force_style='Fontsize=22,OutlineColour=&H55000000,BorderStyle=3'" rescale.mp4
```

Simple filters can be connected with commas. Filters that have more than one output and/or input are to be connected with semicolons.